# WLST: deploy application but do not start it -- how?

Tags: weblogic, deployment, weblogic9.x, wlst

I need to script an EAR deployment to Weblogic 9.2. Extra requirements I have though are:

- Application Name shall be the one I provide, not just EAR name
- Application is deployed in Prepared state, not Running one

As far as I can tell, when I use deploy(), the name is got assigned by me (good!), but application starts right away (bad! other services are not ready yet!).

Can anyone point me to a correct way of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you're looking for is [`distributeApplication`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/config_scripting/reference.html#wp1260412), not `deploy` (also see [Administration Mode for Isolating Production Applications](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/deployment/understanding.html#wp1050830)).

For the application name, why don't you set it in the deployment descriptor?

Comment: Yep, it works. The only catch is that appName shall have a suffix (an EAR with no suffix wouldn't be recognized as such), but it's ok for me. Since I copy EARs under the domain directory, I change their name to contain the version info, and deployed application has it in the name.